# Displaying "stacked" and added exponents in Java

Tags: java, math, exponentiation

So I have been asked to create a program that can evaluate and print the value of...

0.1 + (0.1)^2 + (0.1)^3 . . . + (0.1)^n

using a while loop. So far I have

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Power
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Double x;
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("What is the maximum power of 0.1?");
      x = input.nextLine;
      Double n = 0.1;
      Int exp = 1;
      while (exp <= x)
      {
         Double Answer = Math.pow(n, exp);  //Had to look this one up
         exp++;
      }
      System.out.print(Answer);
   }
}
```

I'm still having trouble trying to decode the following few Compile-time errors I am getting with this program.

```
Power.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
     x = input.nextLine;
              ^
   symbol:     variable nextLine
   location:   variable input of type Scanner

Power.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
     Int exp = 1;
     ^
    symbol:     class Int
    location:   class Power

Power.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
     System.out.print(Answer);
                      ^
    symbol:     variable Answer
    location:   class Power
```

Any fix? Thanks guys

~Andrew

Comment: Tip: change your title to the actual question you're seeking an answer to, and add the `java` tag to your question (because people will often search/listen around for languages they are familiar with).

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean blank spaces.

Comment: If you solved it, don't put solved in the title. Put the solution as an answer.

Comment: I didn't solve it, that's why. I just caught a stupid mistake and fixed it, thinking that it would, in fact, fix the program as a whole. Still having Compile-time errors, though

Comment: Compile time errors are not what you asked in your question (judging from the current title); your title is more about an algorithm. But if you have compile time errors, you should put them in your question, and not let us guess what those errors are. Have you tried interpreting those compile time errors, what they mean (quite often, they say exactly what the problem is). Or searched for the errors on the web?

Comment: I can predict compile error on this line: `x = input.nextLine;`. It's missing a set of `()`. Once added, it still won't compile, because return value of `nextLine()` is `String` which is not compatible with type of `x` which is `Double`.

Comment: Add the full compile time errors to your question; simple copy-paste them.

Comment: added errors to question, and Andreas, changing `x = input.nextLine;`  to  `x = input.nextDouble();` fixed that particular problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Power
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Double x;
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("What is the maximum power of 0.1?");
      x = input.nextDouble(); //Use nextDouble to take in double
      Double n = 0.1;
      int exp = 1;
      Double Answer = 0.0; //You have to declare Answer outside of the while loop below or else Answer will be undefined when you try to print it out in the last line.
      while (exp <= x)
      {
         Answer = Math.pow(n, exp);
         exp++;
      }
      System.out.print(Answer);
   }
}
```

Comment: You're a savior! Thanks mate, and sorry for all the confusion. I'm new here, don't hurt me. Haha

Comment: @AndrewM No problem. Next time post the specific issue along with the piece of code that you think is causing it.  Always post the output trace or else we will have no idea how to go about helping you.